# How to group the same values in a sequence with LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a sequence. For example:

```
new [] { 10, 1, 1, 5, 25, 45, 45, 45, 40, 100, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3 }
```

Now I have to remove duplicated values without changing the overall order. For the sequence above:

```
new [] { 10, 1, 5, 25, 45, 40, 100, 1, 2, 3 }
```

How to do this with LINQ?

Comment: What should be returned in the case of `1,1,2,3,3,1`?

Comment: As you said, it's not grouping, it's removing the duplicated item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var list = new List<int> { 10, 1, 1, 5, 25, 45, 45, 45, 40, 100, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3 };
        List<int> result = list.Where((x, index) =>
        {
            return index == 0 || x != list.ElementAt(index - 1) ? true : false;
        }).ToList();
```

This returns what you want. Hope it helped.

Comment: Please mark it as correct answer if it is solution for your problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
var list = new List<int> { 10, 1, 1, 5, 25, 45, 45, 45, 40, 100, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3 };

var result = list.Where((item, index) => index == 0 || list[index - 1] != item);
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Did you try [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx)?</strike>

```
var list = new [] { 10, 20, 20, 5, 25, 45, 45, 45, 40, 100, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3 };
list = list.Distinct();
```

**Edit**: Since you apparently only want to group items with the same values *when consecutive*, you could use the following:

```
var list = new[] { 10, 1, 1, 5, 25, 45, 45, 45, 40, 100, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3 };

List<int> result = new List<int>();
foreach (int item in list)
    if (result.Any() == false || result.Last() != item)
        result.Add(item);
```

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: That's not true.

Comment: The order should be maintained (changed the example in description).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Contains and preserve order

```
List<int> newList = new List<int>();

foreach (int n in numbers)
    if (newList.Count == 0 || newList.Last() != n)
       newList.Add(n);
var newArray = newList.ToArray();
```

OUTPUT:

> 10, 1, 5, 25, 45, 40, 100, 1, 2, 3

Comment: Nope. Output: 10,1,5,25,45,40,100,2,3

Answer (score 1):

It may be technically possible (though I don't think you can with a one-liner) to solve this with LINQ, but I think it's more elegant to write it yourself.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> PackGroups<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e)
    {
        T lastItem = default(T);
        bool first = true;
        foreach(T item in e)
        {
            if (!first && EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(item, lastItem))
                continue;
            first = false;
            yield return item;
            lastItem = item;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
int[] packed = myArray.PackGroups().ToArray();
```

It's unclear from the question what should be returned in the case of `1,1,2,3,3,1`. Most answers given return `1,2,3`, whereas mine returns `1,2,3,1`.

Comment: @alexey: This is the only correct answer so far.  I don't understand why the other (wrong) answers deserve up votes.

Comment: Because nearly everyone misunderstood the question.

Comment: @KendallFrey: Downvoting every other answer that was even correct before OP has changed the requirement, is not a good style.

Comment: @Tim: I know. I didn't. I only commented that they were wrong. Downvotes are intended to be directed toward the *answer*, not the *answerer*. :(